# How can I properly convert the following Jquery to pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I convert the Jquery below to pure JavaScript?

```
var $buttons = jQuery("#thePaginator li a");
for (var index = 0; index < $buttons.length; index++) {
    var $button = $buttons.eq(index);
    $button.click(function() {
        var newPage = $(this).data("page");
        jQuery("#attribute-myAttribute").val(newPage);
        jQuery("#update").click();
    });
}
```

I wouldn't normally ask a question like this, but the conversion has been difficult, especially with the event listener. Here is what I have so far:

```
runPaginate();
function runPaginate(){
    var buttonArray = document.getElementById("paginator_TCC").querySelectorAll('li');
    for(i=0;i<(buttonArray.length);i++){
        buttonArray[i].addEventListener('click', runUpdate);
    }
}

function runUpdate(){
    console.log("runUpdate started")
    // will need to add code in here for update
}
```

update (in Jquery) is a method that is called to update attributes on the page. Consider the runUpdate function to suffice for that method call.

I believe that I'm having so much trouble because I'm dealing with HTML Collection, so when I get the li elements (which are actually buttons) I can't seem to add an event listener to them. Below is the inspection result from Dev Tools:

```
<div id="thePaginator" class="simple-pagination">
 <ul>
  <li class="disabled">
   <span class="current prev">Prev</span>
  </li>
  <li class="active">
   <span class="current">Year 1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="disabled">
   <span class="current next">Next</span>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: you are looking for '#thePaginator li a' but there is no anchor tag there is span.

Comment: Find solution here https://jsbin.com/fuvebicepu/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @GouravMakhija I looked at your solution and you are still using Jquery for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a `for...of` loop, and move the callback into the loop. That way you can access the iterator:

```
 for(const button of buttonArray){
    button.addEventListener('click', function runUpdate() {
      const { data } = button.dataset;
      //...         
    });
 }
```

Comment: So, when I use var buttonArray = document.getElementById("paginator_TCC").querySelectorAll('li'); then your solution, the event listener is triggered, which is a big step in the right direction. I actually came across a solution similar to this on another website. Thank you!

Comment: So I attempted to assign the dataset to the newPage variable and output that to the console. -> var newPage = this.dataset .page;   and I get undefined in the console. Any ideas how I can properly convert that line of Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

This is the JS equivalent of your jQuery (this just replaces the jQuery method calls with their equivalent JS method calls)

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#thePaginator li a');
for(var index = 0; index < $buttons.length; index++) {
  var button = buttons[index];
  button.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    var newPage = this.dataset.page;
    document.getElementById('attribute-myAttribute').value = newPage;
    document.getElementById('update').click();
  })
}
```

Comment: Are you implying that your answer won't execute? I tried testing your code to test if the event listener you have can get triggered, and thus far, it can't.